# Probability of three certain number to be in ascending order in a set of random numbers

Tags: probability

The numbers 1,2,3,...,n are randomly placed(are mixed). Which is the probability of the numbers 4,5,6 to be in ascending order and consecutive?

Comment: Show please your attempts.

Comment: Well, the ascending part is easy, because whatever sequence you have, if you highlight the 4, 5 and 6, there are only $3!$ ways you can order them. So the probability that they are in ascending order is $\frac{1}{3!} = \frac{1}{6}$. As for the 'consecutive' part, I would consider the numbers 4, 5, 6 as one inseparable element in the sequence. So then we have $n-3$ numbers left, plus this element that has the numbers inside. So then we have to order $n-2$ elements.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $n\ge6$ such that $4,5,6$ are in the list, there are $n!$ ways to arrange the $n$ numbers. Of these ways, there are $n-2$ possible positions in which $4,5,6$ can lay consecutively. In each of the positions which $4,5,6$ can lay consecutively, there are $(n-3)!$ ways to arrange the remaining numbers. So the probability of this event occuring is given by the number of ways in which the event can occur divided by the total number of possible events:
$$\frac{(n-2)\times(n-3)!}{n!}=\frac{1}{n(n-1)}$$